# Add new values in array PHP

Tags: php

for example this is my current array

```
$names[] = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
];
```

I want to add new values in some conditions like

```
if(somecondition){
   $names[] = [
      'Bobby',
      'Nail',
   ]
}
```

So the final array would be like this

```
$names[] = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
   'Bobby',
   'Nail',
];
```

Comment: May I know if the first code is your initialization or an update to the current array?

Comment: ```print_r(array_merge($names[0], $secondNames[0]));```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to add the new elements at the same level in the array. Note that you shouldn't use `[]` after `$names` in your initial assignment (otherwise you will get a multi-dimensional array):

```
$names = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
];
if(somecondition){
   $names = array_merge($names, [
      'Bobby',
      'Nail',
   ]);
}
```

If you need to add the names using `[]` you can add them one at a time:

```
if(somecondition){
   $names[] = 'Bobby';
   $names[] = 'Nail';
}
```

Comment: array (
    0 => 'arr1',
    1 => 'arr1',
    2 => 'arr1',
    3 => 'arr1',
    4 => 'arr1',
    5 => 'arr1',
   
  ),
  1 => 'arr12',
  2 => 'arr12',
  3 => 'arr12',
  4 => 'arr12',
)

Comment: I just merged nested

Comment: Did you see the change I made to your initial assignment as well? (remove the `[]` in that line)

Comment: Is there another way? because I have to use [].

Comment: Why do you have to use `[]`?

Comment: I am trying to continue another one's codes. I think it has to use because of the requirements of the current library. But I found the another way I just added the strings. like if(condition){ $bobby = "bobby"} then added $bobby to the current array's last index .

Comment: I updated the answer. It might be the one that you are hoping for.

Comment: Yes that will work if you just add them one at a time instead of as an array.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria in general, you shouldn't make edits that change the way code works. Instead, make a comment to the author to suggest the change. Such edits are almost always rejected.

Comment: @YanMyoAung I've added to my answer so that it uses `[]`

Comment: @Nick I think your answer is right but when I use it it would encounter the error in some function of library. PHP Error:  [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: @YanMyoAung that means the value was not an array. If it was an empty variable before you might need to make it an array first using `$var = [];` or `$var = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `array_push()` function

```
$names = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
];
if(somecondition){
   array_push($names, 'Bobby', 'Nail');
}
```

and then just call `$names` again

Answer (score 0):

New values can be added in array using [] or using array_push as well.
using array_push:

```
$names = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
];
if(somecondition){
   array_push($names, 'Bobby', 'Nail');
}
```

using [] you can add them one at a time:

```
$names = [
   'John',
   'Bryan',
   'Sersi',
    ];
if(somecondition){
   $names[] = 'Bobby';
   $names[] = 'Nail';
}
```

A small comparison between array_push() and the $array[] method, the $array[] seems to be a lot faster.

```
<?php
$array = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100000; $x++)
{
    $array[] = $x;
}
?>
//takes 0.0622200965881 seconds
```

and

```
<?php
$array = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100000; $x++)
{
    array_push($array, $x);
}
?>
//takes 1.63195490837 seconds
```

so if your not making use of the return value of array_push() its better to use the $array[] way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should use array_push emaple:

```
    $names = [
       'John',
       'Bryan',
       'Sersi',
    ];

    if(somecondition){
       array_push($names, 'Bobby', 'Nail');
    }

var_dump($names);
```